# How do I get msbuild to display console input/output?

Tags: git, msbuild

I have an MSBuild file that pulls our source code down from our central git server and then builds the code to verify that nobody has broken the build.

This works great, except in some cases, people will run it locally and their SSH keys aren't setup properly. If you run the git commands from the command line outside of msbuild, you'll get challenged for your password, and that's an immediate indication that your ssh keys aren't setup correctly.

But if you run the target from the msbuild project, the console input never appears and to the user the build file is hung. How can I let the user know that the build is waiting for their password?

Additionally, when you clone a repo from git it normally gives you status updates for the number of objects that it's downloading. These messages seem to be suppressed when running via msbuild. How do I "hookup" the output from my task to the output of the build so it shows up in the console?

Comment: Consider adding the relevant exec commands or targets from the msbuild script as examples in your question.

Comment: Try building with diagnostic logging enabled and see if you get more detailed information including console output on the failing targets and tasks.